# How to choose a default keyboard layout when one language uses two keyboard layouts?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, input-languages

Under Windows 10, I have an English (United States) language set as default, but there are two keyboard layouts underneath it: US and Serbian (Latin).

I actually need both layouts: my laptop has a Serbian physical keyboard and that's what I primarily use, but I occasionally attach a US physical keyboard to it.

When I start Windows (or wake-up the laptop from sleep), US is selected as the current layout, but I'd like Serbian layout as default because I'll type on my laptop's keyboard in most cases. Sure, I can switch manually, but I often forget to do it after boot or wake-up, until I realize the wrong characters are appearing on my screen.

Is there a way to set Serbian layout as default while still being able to manually switch to US layout?<sup>1</sup>

---

*<sup>1</sup> Obviously, this has nothing to do with these specific layouts - I'm just using them as an example that happens to be relevant in my case.*

Comment: Which layout was installed first?

Comment: I believe it was the US layout (it was probably automatically installed with the US language itself).

Comment: You can choose default in regional options under control panel. Go to keyboard properties.

Comment: @jiggunjer Where exactly?

Comment: controlPanel→Region and Language→Keyboards and Languages tab→Change keyboards→General tab. There is a drop down menu for default input language, just select the layout you want.

Comment: @jiggunjer Thanks, but that doesn't exist under Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default input language on the welcome screen from the Administrative language settings.

Go to **Window Settings** > **Time & Language** > **Region & language**

Then under '**Related settings**' click on '**Administrative language settings**'. Under '**Welcome screen and new user accounts**' you can click on the '**Copy settings...**' button.

This dialog allows you to copy the current language settings to the Welcome screen and for new user accounts.

[image]